# Get height & width of custom HTML tag in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have created custom html tag in iframe. From parent I try to get an element height and width when the pointer hovers on that element. Does anybody have any idea how to get height and width that element? It works in Firefox but in chrome it always returns 0.

Example :

1. In iframe I used custom tag like this : `<item></item>`
2. I access that element from parent like this :

```
$('#iframe').load(function(){
    $('#iframe').contents().find("item").hover(
        function(){
            var height = $(this).height();
            var width = $(this).width();
            console.log("Height : "+height+" | Width : "+width);
            // it's always return 0 in chrome
        },
        function(){

        },
    );
});
```

I think the problem is because chrome doesn't recognize custom html tag. But I'm not really sure about that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i think the problem lies with the following query: .contents().find("item"). You should try to remove .contents(). If that doesn't work, can you post the most important parts of your html as well?

Comment: There are no “custom elements” in HTML. Why would you do that anyway, instead of using an existing HTML element?

Comment: Have you checked with "Inspect element" what is the computed style dimensions for those elements?

Answer (score 0):

the doctype must be valid like `<!DOCTYPE html >` and put display block on the 'item' element

Comment: hey,thanks for the answer. I've set the display into "inline-block". It's worked, thanks a lot.